# Are there any websites that monitor new R packages in the CRAN package repository?

Tags: r, cran

Are there any websites that monitor new R packages in CRAN package repository? Data+name+short description? Or maybe R-CRAN offers a monthly document listing the new packages added to CRAN archive, but I don't see any.

It would be a good feature for finding new R functionalities.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Dirk Eddelbuettel's](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/) [CRANberries](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/cranberries/index.html) site provides this.  You can subscribe to [new](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/cranberries/cran/new), [updated](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/cranberries/cran/updated), and [removed](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/cranberries/cran/removed) packages.

Comment: And besides the RSS subscriptions it also tweets as @CRANberriesFeed.

Answer (score 5):

An alternative is to look at the CRAN packages by date:

http://lib.stat.cmu.edu/R/CRAN/web/packages/available_packages_by_date.html

Answer (score 4):

There's also http://crantastic.org/.

Comment: I think this was recently removed/deleted